# Searching user names in multiple files and print if it doesn't exist using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file which consists of number of users which I need to compare it with multiple files and print if any particular user is not present in the files with filename.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{print $1}' $1 | while read -r line; do
if ! grep -q "$line" *.txt;
then
echo "$line User doesn't exist"
fi
done
```

In the above script, passing user_list file as $1 and can able to find the users for single target file, but it fails for multiple files.

File contents:

```
user_list:
Johnny
Stella
Larry
Jack

One of the multiple files contents:
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
Stella:x:1:1:Admin:/bin:/bin/bash
Jack:x:2:2:admin:/sbin:/bin/bash
```

Usage:

```
./myscript user_list.txt
```

Desired output:

```
File1:
Stella doesn't exist
Jack doesn't exist

File2:
Larry doesn't exist
Johnny doesn't exist
```

Any suggestion here to achieve it for multiple files with printing filename headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop to iterate over each file and execute your code for each file separately.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.txt; do
    echo $f:
    awk '{print $1}' $1 | while read -r line; do
        if ! grep -q "$line" $f
        then
            echo "$line doesn't exist"
        fi
    done
    echo 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do simply

```
for file in *.txt; do 
  echo "$file"
  grep -Fvf "$file" "$1"
  echo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in *.txt; do           ##: Loop through the *.txt files
  for j; do                  ##: Loop through the argument files, file1 file2 file3
    printf '\n%s:\n' "$j"    ##: Print one of the multiple files.
    while read -r lines; do  ##: Read line-by-line & one-by-one all the *.txt files
      if ! grep -q "$lines" "$j"; then  ##: If grep did not found a match.
        printf "%s not doesn't exist.\n" "$lines" ##: Print the desired output.
      fi
    done  < "$f"
  done
done
```

The `*.txt` files should be in the current directory, otherwise add the absolute path, e.g. `/path/to/files/*.txt`

Howto use.

```
./myscript file1 file2 file3 ...
```

- The downside is you're running `grep` `line-by-line` on each files as opposed to what `@Quasimodo` did.